# How to find Nimi field only with max Vanus?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Nimi
FROM Myyjad
WHERE Myyjad.KauplusID
IN (SELECT KauplusID
FROM Kauplused
WHERE Kauplused.Kauplus = [Kauplus?])
AND Myyjad.Vanus > 60
ORDER BY Myyjad.Vanus DESC;
```

The initial task is: By the name of the store (through the parametric window), display the names of the oldest customers of this store.
I need condition where Myyjad.Vanus is the biggest (I can't use MAX func).
Please check relationships in on the link below.

[relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWMt0.png)

[sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxh3t.png)

[sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jybhu.png)

Comment: Can you share the sample data, Moreover if you don't want to use ```MAX``` you can try using ```Window fnction/aalytical functions like row_number ```

Comment: The initial task is: By the name of the store (through the parametric window), display the names of the oldest customers of this store.

Comment: Relationships showing circular referencing. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/38655/prevent-circular-references-in-database-design. Data samples should be provided as text tables and/or CREATE and INSERT action SQL - not images.

Comment: Consider http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Nimi
FROM Myyjad
WHERE Myyjad.KauplusID
IN (SELECT KauplusID
FROM Kauplused
WHERE Kauplused.Kauplus = [Kauplus?])
ORDER BY Myyjad.Vanus DESC;
```